# How can I get a list of a single field value from an entity?

Tags: jpa, jhipster

I am working on a Jhipster app Java service and Angular 5 UI. I have an entity working fine, but I need to get a list of one of the fields (customer) from that entity to display in the UI.

In this case it's a single table I am using which contains the client name, so I am trying to get a distinct list returned for read only.

I have tried creating a custom repository and added a function into the service, Impl class and resource class.

Upon startup its failing with cannot find a property getClientNameList on the entity.

I have show a snippet of the code from the Entity class, the custom repository and the method I added into the PostsServiceImpl class.

Can someone please steer me in the right direction?

Thanks.

```
// Entity Class //
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Posts implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="client_name")
    private String clientName;

    // Other fields here
    ...
}

// Custom Repository //
@Repository
public interface JobsRepositoryCustom {
    List<String> getClientNameList();
}

// PostsServiceImpl //
public class PostsServiceImpl implements PostsService {

    EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<String> getClientNameList() {

        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT clientName FROM Posts", Posts.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Comment: @GaëlMarziou added some, hope that helps to give you an idea of where I am.

Comment: Well I'm a bit confused by your code but maybe it's due to seeing not real code.Why not simply extending your spring data repository as in the doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior? I don't see the link between default repository and custom one. Why using a native query and at same time referring to field name clientName rather than column name client_name? It's SQL or HQL/JPQL not a mix.

Comment: What purpose does `JobsRepositoryCustom`  serve here? Are you using Spring Data? Your question is unclear and needs clarified.

Answer (score 1):

Your error might be more specifically that `clientName` is not found. It is not found because if you run a native query you need to use the database column names.

So change:

```
"SELECT clientName FROM Posts"
```

to

```
"SELECT client_name FROM Posts"
```